# Why does Object.entries return a union type?

Tags: typescript

I'm using the following code, with typescript 4.7.3, and don't understand why the type of `amount` isn't `PositiveNumber`.

```js
export type PositiveNumber = number & { __type: 'PositiveNumber' }
export type PointsByAbbrev = Record<string, PositiveNumber> & { __type: 'PointsByAbbrev' }
export const isPointsByAbbrev = (value: Record<string, number> | null | undefined): value is PointsByAbbrev => hasValue(value) && Object.values(value).every(x => x >= 0)

class Foo {
    data!: PointsByAbbrev
    
    generate(input: Record<string, number>) {
        if (isPointsByAbbrev(input))
            this.data = input
    }

    someMethod(): void {
        Object.entries(this.data).forEach(([abbrev, amount]) => {
        })
    }
}
```

According to the compiler, the type of `amount` is `PositiveNumber | "PointsByAbbrev"`

I'm assigning the `data` via a process like the `generate` method shows where I pass the input through the type guard and then assign if true.

Comment: `PointsByAbbrev` must have a property  `'__type'` with the type of `'PointsByAbbrev'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do some variety of newtype pattern with that `__type` field, but that doesn't make the field any less real. As far as Typescript is concerned, `__type` is a valid slot on your object and its type is `'PointsByAbbrev'`. The type of `this.data` is

```
Record<string, PositiveNumber> & { __type: 'PointsByAbbrev' }
```

The fields of `Record<string, PositiveNumber>` have type `PositiveNumber`, and the fields of `{ __type: 'PointsByAbbrev' }` have type `'PointsByAbbrev'`, so the entire intersection type's fields have type `PositiveNumber | 'PointsByAbbrev'`

Comment: I was using it for type guards. So inside the foreach, do I just do `const value = amount as PositiveNumber`?

Comment: That depends. Does `__type` exist at runtime, or was it cast into existence by your code? If there's an actual `__type` field on your objects, then that cast will fail. If you did `as PointsByAbbrev` on your value earlier and it doesn't *actually* have that field, it'll be fine. But since you mention type guards, I'm guessing the field actually exists and you need to do a real check.

Comment: I updated my question to show the type guard and assignment. It was cast into existence by my code.

Comment: In your case, the `as` cast should be fine. You also might be able to get around having to cast *at all* by making your fake `__type` field a [symbol](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html) rather than the string `'__type'`, since `Object.entries` doesn't include symbol fields. YMMV on whether that's worth it.